# How to handle the size of a bitmap by device : 'Density independence or Alternative bitmaps'

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmapimage

I use images as backgrounds. I found that there is a way to save images by hdpi, mdpi, .. in search results.

The question is, I use 60 images for each device,
is there any capacity or performance issue?

If there are a lot of images, 
what is the best way to process them by device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any capacity or performance issue?

Yes. Too many images can make your app size increase significantly and if your images are not loaded efficiently, your app will be lag

You can use library such as Picaso or Glide to load your images, read more about how to load bitmap efficiently [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap)

Comment: Thank you for answer. The link to image loading was also very helpful. I want to know a little more finely. when processing images by device, is it best to handle dp and load? (if there are many images)

Comment: If the number of images is small, do i manage images by device size?

Comment: For example, all small icons can be put in "drawable-nodpi". For large images, you should put it in "drawable-mdpi", "drawable-hdpi", ... but it will cause your app increase in size. A solution is building multiple APKs, you can read it here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits

Comment: Search results Many people have seen bitmaps added and managed by device size. I wonder why people use this mainly. (not use dp)